# Go waste or go wasted?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder which of the following is correct? *Go waste* or *go wasted*? Two examples:

- I have spent a lot of time on this project. I really do not want my efforts to go waste(d).
- If you do not practice regularly, your talent may go waste(d).

I have seen contradicting evidence on this topic. On the one hand, it seems to me that an *adjective* should be used after *go*. For example, we say *he went aggressive* where *aggressive* is an adjective. In this sense, *wasted* is preferred over *waste*. On the other hand, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+waste%2C+go+wasted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20waste%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20wasted%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgo%20waste%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20wasted%3B%2Cc0) seems to suggest that *go waste* is more popular than *go wasted*.

Another related term I've seen is *go **to** waste*. I would appreciate it if you could also comment on this expression. Is it correct?

Comment: Looking at Google Books suggests that "go waste" may be an Indian English usage.  US and UK usage is "go *to* waste", as James K says.  Also, be careful with Ngrams searches - a lot of the results for "go waste" are actually for sentences like "how to **go waste**-free" or even "Where should it **go?  Waste** has to go somewhere."

Comment: Not to be confused with "get wasted", which is slang for "To get drunk or highly inebriated" - see [new word submission to Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/8682/Get+wasted)

Comment: We don't say "he went aggressive". "he got aggresssive" is the correct form.

Comment: "For example, we say _he went aggressive_" — you may hear native speakers say it this way sometimes, but I'd say this is non-standard. Better to say "he became aggressive". (Reading it without tone of voice/context, I thought that you meant "went" as in "left" — "he went aggressively" — and it was pretty confusing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct standard native speaking phrase is either:

- to go to waste
- to be wasted

Both of these are grammatically correct and commonly used in standard conversation.

"he went aggressive" is not grammatically correct in standard native English.

Comment: If you explain why "he went aggressive" is ungrammatical and suggest how to fix it, it's +1 from me (on condition that I agree with your solution).

Comment: To muddy the waters here, "going <adjective>" can be grammatical, as in "he went crazy." Furthermore, in gaming communities you will actually see the phrase "he went aggro" which is short for "he went aggressive."

Answer (score 26):

The idiom is "[Go to waste](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-to-waste)".  Your other alternatives are wrong.

Alternatively you can just say "... you may waste your talent."

Comment: "Your other alternatives are wrong." In this context, at least. Something like "What are your plans for the concert?" "I'm going to go wasted," would be correct - the second speaker would be saying that they plan to go to the concert while drunk or otherwise highly inebriated.

Comment: You can also say "be wasted".

Comment: Just to be clear, "go wasted" in OP's examples above is grammatically correct and easily understood, it's just less idiomatic than most native speakers would phrase it.  "Be wasted" might be more natural and slightly more literally correct.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis , I disagree. "Be wasted" is fine, and literal. "Go to waste" is a correct idiom. All the alternatives in the OP's question are illogical as naturally construed, and do not mean what the OP seems to be inquiring about; they seem to be some strange middle-ground between the literal phrase and the idiom, which ends up meaning something different than either.

Answer (score 3):

Fully correct here are:

... be wasted

- I have spent a lot of time on this project. I really do not want my efforts to be wasted.
- If you do not practice regularly, your talent may be wasted

and

... go to waste

- I have spent a lot of time on this project. I really do not want my efforts to go to waste.
- If you do not practice regularly, your talent may go to waste.

---

"... go wasted." is **not** incorrect but is less commonly used.
This wording may jar slightly with some English speakers but would not be incorrect.

- I have spent a lot of time on this project. I really do not want my efforts to go wasted.
- If you do not practice regularly, your talent may go wasted

Comment: I think if you wrote the sentences out in full it would be a great improvement otherwise visitors and learners will have to check the OP to remind themselves of the examples. I know I did.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good point. Edited